# Is awk able to extract matched grouping as perl?

Tags: bash, awk

```
echo "file:/home/todd/a.txt, size:123, md5sum:112sdfddddd, status:success" \
 | awk '/file:(.*), size:(.*),/ { print $1 $2}'
```

Actually, I want to extract "/home/todd/a.txt" and "123", but the $1 and $2 is not for it. Is there method for extracting matched grouping as perl?

Answer (score 2):

you can use gensub in gawk for backreferences support, however, generally, you can just do this

```
echo "file:/home/todd/a.txt, size:123, md5sum:112sdfddddd, status:success" | awk -F"," '{
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if( $i~/^file|size/ ){
       split($i, f,":")
       print f[2]
    }
   }
}'
```

Logic: Split on commas, go through each field, check for file or size, then split on ":" to get the 2nd element.

Answer (score 1):

`gawk` has the `gensub()` function which has the *back references* you refer to.  However, I would suggest using `sed` for this if you don't want to use something other than `perl`

`awk` works best when you think of things in terms of *fields*. In your case you could use both the colon `:` and comma `,` as field separators to strip out your text like so:

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{print $2,$4}'
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ echo "file:/home/todd/a.txt, size:123, md5sum:112sdfddddd, status:success" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $2,$4}'
/home/todd/a.txt 123
```

Comment: actually, i need to match several different patterns, and act differently, so i choose awk.

Comment: @Todd see my suggestion on using fields

Comment: nice! I found if i use -F '[:,]', awk still consider space ' ' as the separator, how can i avoid this? i don't want ' ' considered as separator sometimes.

Comment: @Todd: I don't believe that is the case. I think what you are seeing is an empty field. Can you give an example line where this behavior happens?